# Parsing soap web service and making list view

Tags: android, soap

I am new to Android.

I have been googling a lot, but I can't find a preferred example or tutorial for this.

Basically, I just want to parse a web service that is made in `Soap .net` and make a list view from web service data.

Please refer me to any example you might know of. I just want an example of parsing soap web service and making list view in Android.

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-ksoap2-android-and-parsing-output-data

Comment: ya i seen this example but here where is listview made... ?

Comment: and yes i need example for non primitive type SOAP element...

Comment: You should have mentioned in your question that you want to parse non-primitive SOAP objects. Anyway, I have added an answer for custom objects. It should do the job for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1 :** Call the web-service using `KSOAP2` library and parse the data into an array of objects.

*(`MyObject` is the custom user-defined non-primitive object that I have used here and `myObjectArray` is the array of objects which stores the data)*

```
public void getData()
    {
        try {

            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD);

            //request.addProperty("", ""); // incase you need to pass parameters to the web-service

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                    SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);


            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
            int childCount = result.getPropertyCount();
            SoapObject tempArray[] = new SoapObject[childCount];
            for (i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            tempArray[i] = (SoapObject) result.getProperty(i);

            myObjectArray[i] = new MyObject(
                    Integer.parseInt(tempArray[i].getProperty(0).toString()),
                     ....... // get individual data members of each object using getProperty(index)
                    Integer.parseInt(tempArray[i].getProperty(n).toString()));

        }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

**Step 2 :** Display the array of objects in your ListView.

```
ArrayAdapter<MyObject> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<MyObject>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myObjectArray);

mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```